# Error to Run .net Exe on win 8 - 32 bit PC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

We have 3 different PC having visual studio, an application is working fine on all systems while when trying same application on a PC which does not have Visual studio, when try to run , nothing happened, no error message.

we are using dll concept like , native dll using in CLR project and CLR dll is using in C# project.

application log [ application error + .net runtime error] from event viewer is as below:-

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          07-09-2016 15:01:07
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      QC4.bankgrp.com
Description:
Faulting application name: F.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x57ce924d
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17031, time stamp: 0x530888f8
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000f097
Faulting process id: 0xeb4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d208ea8fd94e6b
Faulting application path: C:\dzQCD\F.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: cdb58a94-74dd-11e6-9de9-001d606bc204
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-09-07T09:31:07.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>194144</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>QC4.bankgrp.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>F.exe</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>57ce924d</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.3.9600.17031</Data>
    <Data>530888f8</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>0000f097</Data>
    <Data>eb4</Data>
    <Data>01d208ea8fd94e6b</Data>
    <Data>C:\dzQCD\F.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>cdb58a94-74dd-11e6-9de9-001d606bc204</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>




Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          07-09-2016 15:01:07
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      QC4.bankgrp.com
Description:
Application: F.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at CardBrowser.QCForm..ctor()
   at CardBrowser.Home..ctor()
   at CardBrowser.Program.Main()

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-09-07T09:31:07.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>194143</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>QC4.bankgrp.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: F.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at CardBrowser.QCForm..ctor()
   at CardBrowser.Home..ctor()
   at CardBrowser.Program.Main()
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

could anybody tell me how to identify the root cause of this.
Is problem because of missing dll or it is happening because of framework mismatch???

thanks in advance.

**==finding 1 ==**

I used debugdiag and found this below error[image: DebugDiag]

Comment: Try build application with Target platform as `Any CPU`

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu we are doing the same..

Comment: It is a very plain managed exception.  But without any details, that happens when there is no managed code to catch or monitor the exception and provide those details.  You wrote a program that fails in a completely undiagnosable way on any minor mishap, that's going to be a major time sink without any hope of ever getting help on a web site like this.  What you need to do to fix this is entirely unclear from the question.  But the AppDomain.UnhandledException event is crucial.  The DebugDiag utility is a fairly imperfect alternative.

Comment: @Hans could you say that I am missing  try catch statement on very first page which open when .exe clicked??? Anyways I am trying debugdiag utility to get something useful here...

Comment: @HansPassant I tried DebugDiag and finding shared in my questions. Could you please check and comment on it.

Comment: It is just an example of how a very plain file-not-found error became completely undiagnosable.  You now know that there is a problem with CLI_DLL.dll.  You simply forgot to copy a file you need to run your program.  Nobody here can find that file for you.  "or one of its dependencies" is the usual cue, we don't know its dependencies either.  Dollar to donuts that you did not copy [the C runtime files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).  A utility like Process Monitor can show you the name of that file.

Comment: @HansPassant I install VC++ Redestributable package on the system but still got same problem, then i install visual studio 2013 and .exe open on a single click it means CLI_DLL.dll is placed at appropriate place.. Could you advice something useful here now.

Comment: @HansPassant Looking forward for your valueable comment